# php mysql.. can not assign a variable to the field name in the database

Tags: php, mysql, session, variables

i need some help in the query 2 table  albums and images

i need to select from the database some fields between it there is a **`user_id`**

query:

```
  $album_query = mysql_query("SELECT `albums`.`album_id`, `albums`.`timestamp`, `albums`.`name`, LEFT(`albums`.`description`, 50) as `description`, COUNT(`images`.`image_id`) as `image_count`
     FROM `albums`
     LEFT JOIN `images`
     ON `albums`.`album_id` = `images`.`album_id`
     WHERE `albums`.`user_id` = '**here it must take the session created before**'
     GROUP BY `albums`.`album_id`") or die(mysql_error());
```

and here is the chunk of code:

```
<?php 

ob_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
session_start();
}

require_once('include/connect.php'); 



if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
{
    $id=$_GET['user_id'];


}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    $id= $_SESSION['user_id'];
}

else
{
     require_once('index.php');

    exit();

}

 //function to ge the data for the album
 function album_data($album_id)
 {

 }
 //check if the album  belong to the particular user
 function album_check($album_id)
 {
 }

 //get thelist of albums 
 function get_albums()
 {

     $albums = array();
     $album_query = mysql_query("SELECT `albums`.`album_id`, `albums`.`timestamp`, `albums`.`name`, LEFT(`albums`.`description`, 50) as `description`, COUNT(`images`.`image_id`) as `image_count`
     FROM `albums`
     LEFT JOIN `images`
     ON `albums`.`album_id` = `images`.`album_id`
     WHERE `albums`.`user_id` = ''
     GROUP BY `albums`.`album_id`") or die(mysql_error());

     while($albums_row = mysql_fetch_array($album_query))
     {
         $albums[] = array(
                'id' =>$albums_row['album_id'], 
                'timestamp'=>$albums_row['timestamp'],
                'name'=>$albums_row['name'],
                'description'=>$albums_row['description'],
                'count'=>$albums_row['image_count']
         );

     }
     return $albums;
 }


       function create_album($album_name, $album_description)
 {
     $album_name= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($album_name));
     $album_description= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($album_description));

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO albums VALUES('', '" .$_SESSION['user_id']. "', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '$album_name','$album_description')");

     mkdir('uploads/'.mysql_insert_id(), 0744);
     mkdir('uploads/thumbs/'.mysql_insert_id(), 0744);


 }

?>


*elseif(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
    {
        $id= $_SESSION['user_id'];
    }*
```

This is the error because the system do not allow me to assign the album.user_id = $id 
and the database field store a 0

I do not know if i explained my problem in a understandable way

can anyone help me ???

Comment: There was an insert query in the second code before his edit.

Comment: ok i will edit the question again and add the insert query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this line

```
 WHERE `albums`.`user_id` = ''
```

like this:

```
WHERE `albums`.`user_id` = '".$id."'
```

Comment: i added the '".$id."' the system give this error    **Undefined variable: id**  but in the code i did define  $id

Comment: If neither `$_GET['user_id']` or `$_SESSION['user_id']` are set, you call index.php: I wonder if you should use `header('Location: /index.php')` instead. I assume that in index.php the user can login and then the session variable is set.

Comment: so i need to delete header ?? but what meant in the header that if the user try to access this page without  longing in first it will not allow him and redirect him to the home page

Comment: Changing `require_once('index.php');` to `header('Location: /index.php');` will redirect the browser to the login page.